# Must $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{r(k)}{n}$ converge if $r(k) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm working through a problem in probability, and my solution is equivalent to the following question:

Does $r(k) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ imply that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{r(k)}{n}$ converges?

This feels like a basic analysis question, but I'm having trouble making heads or tails of it. Intuitively, it feels like it should converge

If the limit of the sum does not converge, what is a counterexample for r(k)?

---

I suspect there are a handful of similar questions on MSE, but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Yes, and generally, if $r(k)\to r$, then$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nr(k)\to r$$a.k.a. [Cesàro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean)

Comment: This answers it for me—thanks!

Comment: Cool! $\ddot\smile$